# HTML Russian charset - CRON issues

Tags: html, text, utf-8, character-encoding

Hello Stackoverflow lifesavers.

I have a CRON (at Network Solutions) triggering a script (build_homepage.php) that builds a static html page (index.html), based on some php/mysql results. Basic stuff. I do it all the time.

BUT...

When I run the build_homepage.php manual (by loading it in my browser) it outputs the Russian text html page perfectly. The fly in my ointment is that when the CRON runs build_homepage.php, the index.html page created is all "???????" question marks instead of the Cyrillic text.

The HTML5 page has the following header but it doesn't help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

I could *really* use some help here.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use `gettext` in php script?

Comment: no. i do not use "gettext" anywhere in the code.